# coq What tactics should I use forall A : Prop, A -> ~~A

Tags: coq

I do not know what tactics I have to use for prove the formule.
I tried two methods but I'm stuck in the two.

```
Lemma Exo17 : forall A : Prop, ~~(A \/ ~A).
Proof.

Methode 1
intro.
unfold not.
intro.

Methode 2
intro.
intro.
case H.
```

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: I agree that this looks like homework.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best tactic for this case is called "pen and paper". Indeed, you should try first to build the proof by hand [[intuitionistic sequent calculus LJ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequent_calculus#Intuitionistic_sequent_calculus:_System_LJ) should work fine for this purpose].

Once you have a clear picture of how the proof works, coding it in Coq will be trivial.

Comment: Pencil is better than pen, in case you make an error along the way. :-)

Comment: It's not clear to me whether the asker knows about the `trivial` tactic, based on the title of the question.

Comment: Hello, I do not see what I'm supposed to do with the intuitive LJ sequence calculation ^^. I did not know the tactics trivial, in the documentation it says that it solves trivial equalities like X = X but where do I use it in the code. i 'm stuck with A \/ (A -> False) -> False in the hypothesis.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I misran the tactics in my head.  `trivial` is `auto 0`, and will apply single hypotheses, but to solve `forall A : Prop, A -> ~~A`, you actually need `auto 2` (or just `auto`, or judicious use of `apply`).  However, these will not solve the goal in your question text, and I'm a bit confused by the mismatch between your question title and your question text.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `intuition` to solve the problem, then `Print Exo17` to find out what the solution was.

Comment: `intuition` frequently generates suboptimal proof terms, which is, of course, understandable. I guess one has to do an assignment like that by hand to get a better grasp on the subject.

Comment: I took the output of `intuition` and pared it down until I understood what was going on. I would not have thought to use the assumption twice otherwise!